# How to get the currently connected VPN’s name under OS X

Tags: macos, bash, vpn

I know I can get the Wifi SSID by doing

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I | sed -e "s/^  *SSID: //p" -e d
```

but is there a way to get the VPN name that is currently being used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean a VPN service registered with Network Preferences, AppleScript, specifically *System Events*’ *Network Preferences Suite* will work:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell current location of network preferences
        get name of every service whose (kind is greater than 11 and kind is less than 16) and connected of current configuration is true
    end tell
end tell
```

If you need to access this from the shell, `osascript -e` is your friend (one `-e` option per line of AppleScript, mind the quoting and escaping – see `man osascript`).

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Can you explain the kind option? why >11 and <16? How could I have discovered all those option names (current configuration, every service, etc.) myself?

Comment: @nachocab: the `kind` value identifying the, well, kind of network connection is an integer value, with the values 12 to 15 indicating the different types of VPN OS X supports. As to finding out this stuff: study the AppleScript dictionaries of apps (by using the browser in the AppleScript editor), try out what they offer (which is how I got the values you asked about, which are undocumented AFAIK), search the tubes where you get stuck (starting with the Stack Exchange sites and ending with Google, which tends to bubble up popular but outdated solutions).

Comment: @nachocab: also, the `every … whose` clause is standard AppleScript – the so-called *[reference form](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_reference_forms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH4g-120522)*. The AppleScript editor’s help menu will link to the AppleScript Language Guide, which is a always worth a peek into :).